# Script to test RDP connection to Multiple Servers

Tags: python-3.x, powershell

I am New to scripting world.
I have a requirement to test RDP access to our Servers in two datacenter as a part of a Leased Line Migration. I have a little over 2000+ servers and I cannot manually test RDP connection to all of them. I was hoping if any of you can help me prepare a script where I give the IP addresses of all my servers in the script and it tests RDP connections to all those servers and gives me a result if the RDP connection is successful or not.

Thanks in advance
Ravi

Comment: This is a very common thing and a PowerShell beginner step.  It's OK, to be new to things, but you should spend the time getting up to speed on what you need to use. Youtube has tons of videos relative to beginner, intermediate, advanced, etc. on PowerShell. PowerShell has plenty of examples in the help files.  There are specific cmdlets for things like this. See Test-NetConnection.

Comment: SO, rules: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a text file of the server names or read directly from ADDS.
Pass that computername in a pipeline to the Test-NetConnection cmdlet using the CommonTCPPort switch for the RDP protocol in a ForLoop.

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Get-Content).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Get-Content).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Get-Content -Examples
Get-help -Name Get-Content -Full
Get-help -Name Get-Content -Online


(Get-Command -Name Get-ADComputer).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Get-ADComputer).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Get-ADComputer -Examples
Get-help -Name Get-ADComputer -Full
Get-help -Name Get-ADComputer -Online


(Get-Command -Name Test-NetConnection).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Test-NetConnection).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Test-NetConnection -Examples
Get-help -Name Test-NetConnection -Full
Get-help -Name Test-NetConnection -Online
```

[About_loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7)

[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell%20test%20for%20rdp)

***Update***

As per my comment, you should only really need something like this.

```
(Get-ADComputer).Name | 
ForEach {Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $PSItem -CommonTCPPort RDP}
```

Or

```
Get-Content -Path 'D:\ServerNames.txt' | 
ForEach {Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $PSItem -CommonTCPPort RDP}
```

***Update***

A follow-up to your Out-File comment that you put as an answer. Again, step back take the time to learn PowerShell (the built-in help files, Youtube, articles, books, blogs, etc...) to limit/avoid confusion, mistakes, bad coding habits, frustrations as well as possible serious harm to your computer or your environment when create, update, deletes may be a later use case.

So, your file use case is one of these:

```
$env:COMPUTERNAME | 
ForEach {Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $PSItem -CommonTCPPort RDP}

<#
# Results

ComputerName           : Labhost001
RemoteAddress          : ...
RemotePort             : 3389
InterfaceAlias         : ...
SourceAddress          : ...
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : ...
TcpTestSucceeded       : False
#>

You should only need these ....
ComputerName, RemotePort, PingSucceeded, TcpTestSucceeded
... that last property says whether the connection worked.

$env:COMPUTERNAME | 
ForEach {Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $PSItem -CommonTCPPort SMB}


<#
# Results

ComputerName     : Labhost001
RemoteAddress    : ...
RemotePort       : 445
InterfaceAlias   : ...
SourceAddress    : ...
TcpTestSucceeded : True
#>

$env:COMPUTERNAME | 
ForEach {
    Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $PSItem -CommonTCPPort SMB | 
    Select-Object -Property ComputerName, RemotePort, PingSucceeded, TcpTestSucceeded
}  

<#
# Results

ComputerName RemotePort PingSucceeded TcpTestSucceeded
------------ ---------- ------------- ----------------
Labhost001     445         False             True
#>


$env:COMPUTERNAME | 
ForEach {
    Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $PSItem -CommonTCPPort SMB | 
    Select-Object -Property ComputerName, RemotePort, PingSucceeded, TcpTestSucceeded | 
    Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\TNCResults.txt' -Append
}  
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\TNCResults.txt'
<#
# Results

ComputerName RemotePort PingSucceeded TcpTestSucceeded
------------ ---------- ------------- ----------------
Labhost001     445         False             True
#>


$env:COMPUTERNAME | 
ForEach {
    Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $PSItem -CommonTCPPort SMB | 
    Select-Object -Property ComputerName, RemotePort, PingSucceeded, TcpTestSucceeded | 
    Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\TNCResults.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Append
}  

Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\TNCResults.csv'
<#
# Results

"ComputerName","RemotePort","PingSucceeded","TcpTestSucceeded"
"Labhost001","445","False","True"
#>

Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\TNCResults.csv'
<#
# Results

ComputerName RemotePort PingSucceeded TcpTestSucceeded
------------ ---------- ------------- ----------------
Labhost001     445        False         True 
#>
```

Comment: Thank you. I read a little in the links that you provided. Ran the below script in PowerShell ISE. My List of Server IP's are in the test.txt file
***************************************************************************************
$ServerArray = Get-ChildItem (C:\Users\Rkatragadda\Downloads\test.txt)
foreach ($Server in $ServerArray)
{
  Test-Netconnection -Computername $Server -port 3389
  }
***************************************************************************

Comment: But the out is not as expected. Please see below

PS C:\Users\Rkatragadda> $ServerArray = Get-ChildItem (C:\Users\Rkatragadda\Downloads\test.txt)
foreach ($Server in $ServerArray)
{
  Test-Netconnection -Computername $Server -port 3389
  }
 
WARNING: Name resolution of .cisco failed


ComputerName   : .cisco
RemoteAddress  : 
InterfaceAlias : 
SourceAddress  : 
PingSucceeded  : False

Comment: Be sure to note put code block in the comments, they are hard to read and follow for those willing to help. Put this code stuff in your original post. That code block you have on the comments is one of the reasons I suggested you spend some time getting to know PowerShell first. What you did there is overkill for what you are after.

Comment: How can I get the entire output in to a file?

Comment: No worries. To get to a file, just select the properties you want, based on your use case, you don't need them all. You have to pipe results to the path. See the help files on how to use Out-File as well as Export-Csv.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps me a lot

Answer (score 0):

I just worked on this similar task today and got it working successfully.

You will need to create a text file contains the list of servers names or IPs.
In my case, I used two text files:

1. One file for Windows servers "rdp.txt"
2. The second file for Linux servers "ssh.txt"

Then in PowerShell run the following script:

> *Don't forget to update the files paths in lines (2 & 3) according to the directory you place the files in*

```
    #Read the text files contents
    $RDPServers = Get-content 'C:\scripts\rdp.txt'
    $SSHServers = Get-content 'C:\scripts\ssh.txt'
    
    #Define two containers variables to hold the list of reachable and unreachable servers.
    $LiveServer = @()
    $DeadServer = @()
    
    
    #Loop over the windows servers list to test each server connectivity
     foreach($Server in $RDPServers){
        #Test the connectivity to windows server and store the response "True" or "False" in $nettest Variable
        $netest = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $Server -Port 3389 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty TcpTestSucceeded
    
        Write-Output "RDP $($Server) is : $($netest)"
    
        if($netest -eq "True")
            #Add to the $Lifeserers list
            { $LiveServer += "$Server"}
        else 
            #Add to the $DeadServers list
            {$DeadServer += "$Server" }
    
    
       }
    
    echo "..." 
    echo "..." 
    
    #Loop over the Linux servers list to test each server connectivity
    foreach($Server in $SSHServers)
        {
        #Test the connectivity to Linux server and store the response "True" or "False" in $nettest Variable
        $netest = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $Server -Port 22 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty TcpTestSucceeded
    
        Write-Output "SSH $($Server) is : $($netest)"
    
        if($netest -eq "True") { $LiveServer += "$Server"}
        else {$DeadServer += "$Server" }
       }
    
    echo "Test Completed."
   
    Write-Host "Reachable Computer as below"
    $LiveServer
   
    Write-Host "Not Reachable Computer as below"
    $DeadServer
```

Run the script and check the output.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but my suggestion would be to use [nmap](https://nmap.org/).

For example:

```
nmap -Pn -p 22,3389 -iL input_hosts_list -oG nmap_scan_results
```

- `-Pn` skips the ping check to see if the host is alive. You could leave this out, but I'd want to know if the host was listening on the TCP ports even if ICMP wasn't responding.
- `-p 22,3389` will scan only ports 22/tcp and 3389/tcp.
- `-iL` specifies your input file (a list of hostnames and/or IP addresses, one per line).
- `-oG` specifies the output file. There are other output formats that may be more suitable to your use case.

Note that this solution only confirms that the TCP ports are responding, not that 22/tcp is running an SSH server or that 3389/tcp is running an RDP server. That may be sufficient for most cases. There are a number of Lua scripts that can be used with nmap if you are looking for additional information or verification, such as:

- https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/rdp-enum-encryption.html
- https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssh2-enum-algos.html